# How do I write a query that returns the number of records in a particular status out of the last twenty (but only if those twenty happened today?)l

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to write a query that will tell me how many times a test failed in the last twenty attempts (but only counting attempts made today and only if there have been at least twenty attempts today.) I'm particularly interested in just the ones that have failed 10 times or more in the last 20 iterations.

Schema:

```
test_results
-----------------
id
test_id
status (0 failed, 1 passed)
date_ran
```

This is how I far I got before losing the plot:

```
SELECT count(*) as num_failed, test_id 
FROM test_results
WHERE
date_ran > '2011-03-21 00:00:00'
AND
    status = 0
AND
    test_id IN ( -- some sort of subquery that gives me tests that have run
                  at least 20 times today, regardless of status --)
GROUP BY test_id
HAVING num_failed > 9
ORDER BY date_ran DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should return all tests that have run at least 20 times today, of which at least 10 failed.

```
select test_id
      ,count(*)               as num_runs
      ,sum(status)            as passed
      ,count(*) - sum(status) as failed
  from test_results
 where date_ran = current_date
 group 
    by test_id 
having count(*) >= 20
   and count(*) - sum(status) >= 10;
```

I exploited the fact that status=1 can be summed. If you have other values for status, you would need to use a CASE/WHEN expression instead.

Answer (score 0):

use Limit 0, 20 and also instead of using num_failed in HAVING, you need to use count(*) directly-

```
SELECT count(*) as num_failed, test_id 
FROM test_results
WHERE
date_ran > '2011-03-21 00:00:00'
AND
    status = 0
AND
    test_id IN ( -- some sort of subquery that gives me tests that have run
                  at least 20 times today, regardless of status --)
GROUP BY test_id
HAVING count(*) > 9
ORDER BY date_ran DESC
LIMIT 0,20
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select test_id,sum(status=0) as num_failed,count(*) as total from test_results as t1
where (select count(*) from test_results as t2
       where t1.test_id = t2.test_id and t1.date_ran < t2.date_ran) <20 and date_ran > curdate()
group by test_id
having num_failed > 9 and total = 20
```